# How to enabled/disabled submit button based on checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I want to enable submit button when one or more checkbox value is selected , i tried with below code its enabling button but if i check one value its making all checkbox seletced ? Any  idea what is implemented wrong ?

main.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in userList track by $index">
          <td st-ratio="20">{{user.attuid}}</td>
          <td st-ratio="30">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
          <td st-ratio="20"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="userList.selected" ng-click="checkedValue(user)"> </td>
        </tr>

 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="user.selected" ng-disabled="!userList.selected" ng-click="addUsers()">Add User(s)</button>
```

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.$on('show-user-list',function(e,data){
    $scope.userList = data;
    $scope.userList.selected = false;
  });


 $scope.checkedValue = function(user) {
 user._id = user.attuid;
 user.type = 'user';
        if ($scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(user) === -1) {
            $scope.selectedUsers.push(user);
            $scope.userList.selected = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedUsers.splice($scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(user), 1);
        }
        console.log($scope.userList.selected);
    };
```

Comment: yes, the prooblem is `ng-model="userList.selected"` i this it should be 'ng-model=" user .selected"`

Comment: How about the button ?

Comment: updated the answer with an approach to check enabling and disabling of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single scope variable to evaluate with ng-disabled. Something like $scope.userSelected.  Update it based on a user being selected/unselected.

**Controller**

```
$scope.userSelected = false;

$scope.checkedValue = function() {
  $scope.userSelected = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.userList, function(user) {
    if (user.selected) {
      $scope.userSelected = true;
    }
  });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in userList track by $index">
    <td st-ratio="20">{{user.attuid}}</td>
    <td st-ratio="30">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
    <td st-ratio="20">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected" ng-click="checkedValue()"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!userSelected" ng-click="addUsers()">Add User(s)</button>
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/art4ofB4e0tT9aw4CyP1?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you the checkbox value is `ng-model="userList.selected"`, so all the checkboxes have the same value `userList.selected`, therefore all get selected when you check one of them.

**Update** - (to handle disabling and enabling of the adduser button)

How about we have `$scope.selectedUsers`then disable button based on its length `ng-disabled="selectedUsers.length == 0"`

Example Snippet:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.userList = [{
      attuid: "1",
      firstName: "abc",
      lastName: "xyz",
      selected: false
    }, {
      attuid: "2",
      firstName: "abc",
      lastName: "xyz",
      selected: false
    }];
    $scope.selectedUsers = [];
    $scope.checkedValue = function(user) {
      user._id = user.attuid;
      user.type = 'user';
      if ($scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(user) === -1) {
        $scope.selectedUsers.push(user);
        $scope.userList.selected = true;
      } else {
        $scope.selectedUsers.splice($scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(user), 1);
      }
    };

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in userList">
      <td st-ratio="20">{{user.attuid}}</td>
      <td st-ratio="30">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
      <td st-ratio="20">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected" ng-click="checkedValue(user)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="selectedUsers.length == 0" ng-click="addUsers()">Add User(s)</button>
</div>
```